# Looking for Cover letter template

Tags: templates, letters

I'm looking for cover letter template which would fit with this [CV](https://github.com/ynadji/resume/blob/master/cv.tex), [PDF here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~ynadji3/docs/cv.pdf). Can anyone suggest anything similar to that (just a regular cover letter, sender's address on top right, recipients lower on the left, text follows ...).

I'm  newbie to LaTeX, and somewhat short on time, otherwise would have try to compose my own. But as the situation stands, unfortunately, haven't got the time for experimenting :/

Comment: Here is a [list of classes and packages dealing with letters on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/topic/letter)

Answer (score 26):

The [newlfm](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) class or the `scrlttr2` class (from the KOMA-Script bundle) could be an option.

EDIT: here's a simple example adapted from [Matthew J. Miller's template](http://www.matthewjmiller.net/howtos/customized-cover-letter-scripts/)

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno]{newlfm}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{url}

\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

\newlfmP{headermarginskip=20pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{dateskipafter=20pt}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}
\PhrPhone{Phone}
\PhrEmail{Email}

\namefrom{Matthew J.\ Miller}
\addrfrom{%
    \today\\[10pt]
    439 Coordinated Science Laboratory\\
    1308 West Main Street\\
    Urbana, IL 61801
}
\phonefrom{217-244-6024}
\emailfrom{mjmille2@uiuc.edu}

\addrto{%
Faculty Search Committee\\
Department of Computer Science\\
Clemson University\\
Clemson, SC 29634-0974}

\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closeline{Sincerely,}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

I am writing to apply for the position of assistant
professor in Clemson University's Computer Science Department.  I plan to receive my
Ph.D.\ degree from the University of Illinois at
Urbana-Champaign in Summer of 2006.  My adviser is
Prof.\ Nitin H.\ Vaidya, and my general areas of interest
include wireless and sensor network performance and security.
 Having many friends and family in the area, I would be
most enthused to return to the South permanently by accepting
a position at your institution.

In my graduate work, I focus on the design of
energy-efficient protocols and secure key distribution.
More specifically, I have explored various techniques at
multiple layers of the network stack to effectively reduce
the energy consumption of wireless communication.  In security,
my work was the first to propose leveraging channel diversity
for sensor network key distribution.  My research appears in 
the \textit{IEEE Transactions on Mobile Computing} journal as
well as \textit{Infocom 2006} and \textit{ICDCS 2005},
prestigious conferences in the areas of networking and distributed
systems, respectively.

Enclosed is my curriculum vitae (including a list of
publications), contact information for my references, a research
statement, and a teaching statement.  All of my publications and
presentations are available at:

\url{http://www.crhc.uiuc.edu/~mjmille2/publications/}

Please let me know if there are any other materials
or information that will assist you in processing my application.

Thank you for your consideration.  I look forward to
hearing from you.

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps know of a decent looking example letter in any of them? The examples given in newlfm CTAN archive are absolutely hideous.

Comment: @Rook: I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina What defines the `parskip` in this class?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina can you please help me to remove those two horizontal lines at the top and bottom of the page .

Comment: @Altius Add `\noHeadline` and `\noFootline` to the preamble.

Answer (score 0):

In Miktex 2.9 you can choose New File > File From Template > Basic Templates > Letter.

Edit to make this clearer:

I don't know what you are using to write your Latex documents.  I use a free tool called MiKTeX version 2.9 which offers some built-in templates, although you can use document classes for which there are no templates.  As I mentioned it can be downloaded for free.  You could search for "miktex download".

When I go to my start menu and look for Miktex 2.9, I choose Texworks.  That will open an editor.  Using the file menu you choose each of these choices in turn: File > New File from template > Basic Templates > Letter.   This will open a file with some Latex code in it already, a template for a letter.  You can change the code that is there if you want.  Today I had to remove the part that makes a mailing label for the recipient because it showed at the end of my letter which I intend to post online as a cover letter.  I don't need a mailing label.

I don't know about other Latex editors but you might try opening a latex document with:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{letter}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{recipient name and address}
```

if you are using a different editor that does not have templates.

Comment: Please can you explain better with other details your solution? For example I have not understood your solution.

Comment: I use also MiKTeX version 2.9. but for my humble opinion doesn't answer the old question.

Comment: I could not include my whole comment under comments, so I edited my answer.

Comment: I strongly suspect this has nothing to do with MikTeX. I'd bet it is Texworks which provides the templates - an editor which is provided with MikTeX, but doesn't belong to it. You can install Texworks on most Linux distros using your distro's package manager. For Mac, you can probably download one of those flashy installer thingies with an `.app` inside. For Windows, you can download whatever Windows users use to install software. (Sorry, haven't had admin rights on a Windows machine for a very, very long time. I don't remember ever *downloading* an application for it!)

Comment: That may be the case; I don't know.  Texworks came with my Miktex download.  I'm using Windows 10.  However, I think the document class letter should work with other Latex versions, then the user can modify the elements to suit their needs.  As I deleted the address label and I changed the margins.