# Remove header and footer lines in newlfm

Tags: header-footer, newlfm

I'm trying to write a cover letter using the `newlfm` into `\documentclass{...}`.

It's okay for the letter but every page introduces a hideous top and bottom rule line. Has anyone used this and knows how to remove?

The example code I'm using is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15534

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding this to your preamble should work:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\ps@ltrhead}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\g@addto@macro{\ps@othhead}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother
```

It is because the class internally uses the package `fancyhdr` and this is the stardard way to remove the header and footer lines in this package. The class defines two styles, `ltrhead` and `othhead`, this way, we remove the lines from both of them.

Comment: For future viewers, adding `\newlfmP{noLines}` should also work.

Answer (score 5):

THis works too (see screenshots):

```
\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}
```

and see section 10.1 of the `newlfm` [manual](http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/newlfm/newlfm.pdf).

[image]

Full listing:

```
\documentclass[dateright,dateyes,13pt,stdletter]{newlfm}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\greetto{To whom it may concern,}
\closeline{Best regards,}
% one more solution
\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}
\namefrom{Jonh Doe}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
\lipsum[23]
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While this might be a solution it is perhaps better to provide some screenshot to show the result of your proposition!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer done, thanks for the advice!